# How can I repeatedly toggle a CSS animation class without a second click?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I want the colour and size of a div box to animate and return to its original values when a button is clicked. Here is my code example:

```js
document.getElementById("andAction").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("box").classList.toggle("animi");
})
```

```css
.thing {
  transform: translate(150px, 100px);
}

.box {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 2px;
  color: black;
  width:20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}


@keyframes blob {
  0%  { 
         background-color: #999;
      }
  50% { 
        background-color: #F9086D;
        transform: scale(2);
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
  100% { 
        background-color: #999;          
      }
 }

.animi {
  animation-name: blob;
  animation-duration:3s;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
}
```

```html
<button id="andAction" class="button">button</button>

<div id="box" class="box">1</div>
```

#### Problem

My problem is that I am doing it with toggle. Which means I have to click twice on the second time. Another variety was `classList.add` and then remove again. This leads to no result because the animation is not started for the user. the only thing I could do would be to work with timeout.

#### Question

I have the feeling there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some js to remove the class automatically after the animation finished and change your initial behaviour to not toggle but just add the class. You can achieve that by using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event.

```js
const box=document.getElementById("box");

document.getElementById("andAction").addEventListener("click", function() {
  box.classList.add("animi");
});

box.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  box.classList.remove("animi");
});
```

```css
.thing {
  transform: translate(150px, 100px);
}

.box {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 2px;
  color: black;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes blob {
  0% {
    background-color: #999;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #F9086D;
    transform: scale(2);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #999;
  }
}

.animi {
  animation-name: blob;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="andAction" class="button">button</button>

<div id="box" class="box">1</div>
```

Comment: I updated again to not double-bind the animationend event, be sure to copy the latest version of my snippets JS. You can upvote the answer too so it becomes differenciated from other answers even more.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the `onanimationend` event to remove the class when the animation ended without relying on timers that are harder to maintain:

```js
const boxElement = document.getElementById("box")

boxElement.addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
  // if the target it the box (it's triggered by animations on children too)
  // and the animation name is `blob` (it's triggered by any animation)
  // remove the class
  if (e.target === boxElement && e.animationName === "blob") {
    boxElement.classList.remove('animi');
  }
})

document.getElementById("andAction").addEventListener("click", function() {
    boxElement.classList.add("animi");
})
```